# How can I pass values from Highcharts event callbacks (click, mouseOver, mouseOut) back to React component member function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, this

I can create a chart and pass a function for the `mouseOver` event that simply logs the x and y values of the marker that I hover over:

```
// Works

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';

class App extends React.Component {

  render = () => {
    const options = {
      chart: {
        type: 'spline'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'My chart'
      },
      series: [
        {
          data: [1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6]
        }
      ],
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          point: {
            events: {
              mouseOver: function () {
                const point = { x: this.x, y: this.y };
                console.log(point);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Ultimately I want to be able to pass that `point` back to my component and use it elsewhere in my app.

The simple idea of calling a function in my component from within the event does not work -- the `this` that I pass in the `plotOptions` no longer refers to my component but to the point in the chart:

```
// Does not work
// Uncaught TypeError: this.handleMouseOver is not a function

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';

class App extends React.Component {

  handleMouseOver = point => {
    console.log(`handleMouseOver gets ${point}`);
  }

  render = () => {
    const options = {
      chart: {
        type: 'spline'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'My chart'
      },
      series: [
        {
          data: [1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6]
        }
      ],
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          point: {
            events: {
              mouseOver: function () {
                const point = { x: this.x, y: this.y };
                this.handleMouseOver(point);                 <--- not the `this` of my component
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

No surprise, the error that I get in the browser when I hover over a point is

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.handleMouseOver is not a function
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: One solution I found is to put `const foo = this.handleMouseOver;` at the start of the `render` function and call `foo(point)` in the `plotOptions`. This avoids using `this` in the `plotOptions` to refer to the component. Seems a bit of a cheat, though. Is there something more elegant?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using one of these solutions:

1) save the component reference in the chart object like that:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.chart = this.refs.chart.chart;
  this.chart.component = this;
}
```

And use it inside `mouseOver` callback:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    point: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: function() {
          const self = this.series.chart.component;
          const point = {
            x: this.x,
            y: this.y
          };

          self.handleMouseOver(point);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Demo:

- https://codesandbox.io/s/k0o59ljpnr

---

2) use IIFE to save the reference to the component object and then use it inside `mouseOver` callback function:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    point: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: (function(self) {
          return function() {
            const point = {
              x: this.x,
              y: this.y
            };
            self.handleMouseOver(point);
          };
        })(this)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/y0x02o26pz

Comment: Can the same pattern be followed for on `click` event instead of mouseover??

Comment: Yes, the same pattern can be used for a `click` event.

Comment: what if my Chart component is a functional component and I can't use this? also , I have defined my chartOption in another file like chartConfig.js. and export it to my chart component. I also confused with this line : ` const point = {
              x: this.x,
              y: this.y
            };` . where this.x and this.y coms from?